# Setting the "origin" attribute on a dynamic link in a REL DCP

Tags: dynamic-linking, componentpresentation, rel

I have a DCP with Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly checked which I am storing in the database. This DCP is a summary display of a component, and it contains a component link to another component presentation using the same component on a different page. I have the Output Format set to `REL` so that the dynamic link will be resolved at runtime.

Everything generally works, `<tcdl:Link>` tags make it into the `COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS` table and are resolved when the page is rendered. However since this DCP is used on multiple pages I cannot set the origin attribute on the `tcdl:link` tag during publish. I know this means the link resolution will not be cached, it also results in a page linking to itself sometimes. I reviewed some posts, including this one by **Mihai** (**[Passing the PageURI to a DCP for Dynamic Linking](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/passing_the_pageURI_to_a_DCP_for_dynamic_linking.aspx)**) but that only applies to DCPs stored in the file system. I know I can set template priority to solve this problem in this particular instance by making the detail CP higher priority but I'm wondering if there is a way to use the origin attribute properly in this situation.

### Additional Information:

I am using Razor mediator for templating, ASP.NET for delivery, pages and binaries are stored in the file system with everything else in the DB.

My link tag as it exists in the `COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS` table:

```
<tcdl:Link type="Component" origin="tcm:0-0-0" destination="tcm:42-215" templateURI="tcm:0-0-0" linkAttributes=" title=&quot;Available content component types&quot;" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="">Available content component types</tcdl:Link>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Publication Target Language is ASP.NET

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a classic "index page with summaries/teasers pointing to detailed article pages".

My understanding is that the `origin` attribute is there to exclude the current page from the Dynamic Linking algorithm, i.e. it is the URI of the page that list the dynamic link (`this page`).  But when you're rendering a DCP used in multiple pages linking to another DCP also used on multiple pages, you have multiple `origin` values. So this can't be done and Tridion sets the value to "tcm:0-0-0" because that's the best it can do.

What you can do is set the summary CT to not be a Dynamic template.  So render it statically on your index/summary page, and you should be able to specify the `origin` then.

Comment: Any advice on the caching? I'd like to use a DCP from the database for the header, it would likely have a good amount of component links and obviously be loaded frequently. I guess maybe switching to a ascx is my only option.

Comment: When the origin is "tcm:0-0-0" this link will not be cached. If cache is the only concern, then I'd consider "hard-coding" the URI of the home page as origin. If distance to the actual is page is important, then you may need something more creative - perhaps you can get the current page ID from the Ambient Framework (speculating here, but maybe others can pitch in on this idea).

Comment: Instead of a DCP, you can make your header an include page published from Tridion (or publish a page with an ascx extension).  Then you'd have one TCM URI for this page and use the origin.  (P.S. play the Stackexchange game and upvoate - we help in exchange for points :)

Comment: Ha, I don't have enough rep to upvote yet. It sounds like the answer is no and I just don't get to use the origin attribute in this situation. I've got a lot of options to work around it so I will use one of those. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: No problem, then stick around.  Ask, contribute and you'll have some rep in no time.  Glad you have thought through workarounds. Sounds like you know what to do.  Good luck!